# Set value to input type checkbox with JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, checkbox

I am using Spring MVC to create a checkbox like this:

```
<form:checkbox id="idVerifiable" path="verifiable"/>
```

It generates me:

```
<input id="idVerifiable" type="checkbox" value="false" name="verifiable">
```

If I try:

```
$('#idVerifiable').val("true");
```

It sets the value but the checkbox is not checked, how to change this to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#idVerifiable').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: @Jim Bolster glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('#idVerifiable').attr("checked", true);
```

or

```
$('#idVerifiable').prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('input[name=verifiable]').attr('checked', true);
```